# UFT .Highlight is working from repository but not from Action

Tags: vba, qtp, hp-uft

I have some elements in my repo with relative path:

[image]

And i have this code in my Action Solution:

```
Browser("Posventa").Page("Posventa").WebEdit("CampoNroOperacion").Highlight
Browser("Posventa").Page("Posventa").WebElement("DespEventosConPaginado").Highlight
exist = Browser("Posventa").Page("Posventa").WebElement("DespEventosConPaginado").Exist(10)
print("existe en Action: "&exist)
```

So after execute my Action, 1st Highlight is working ok, but the 2d one doesn't work and `exist` equals False.

The object `DespEventosConPaginado` has AVG element, maybe i didn't capture correctly that object.
I tried to add aditional values like `X` and `Y` or `abs_y` and `abs_X` but this did not work.

This is a drop-down that a want to click:

[image]

And when i click manual highlight from my repo, its working fine and the object blinks.

[image]